# IE8 - Site background changes on textarea focus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, internet-explorer-8

I'm currently working on a site that will be used in IE8.
I'm using Bootstrap as my framework.

The issue I'm having is when clicking in a text area (input) on focus my entire background goes white and I've NO clue why.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Before input]

[image: After Input]

You can view the code here:

http://hub.yfish.co.uk/testing/BEST/root-final/

I realize my CSS is somewhat messy - this is a prject I've had barely anytime to work on!

My placeholder text is also not showing (it should be a light grey colour)

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE WITH FIXES:

To fix this issue:

Despite

```
html, body {  
    background-color: #3c3d41;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

My page was loading as white background. To fix that I did:

```
html, body, body:focus {  
    background-color: #3c3d41;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

To fix the background color change I was getting with textareas:

```
body.body-bg {
    background-color: #3c3d41;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your CSS seems to be really messy.. For some reason your have the selector `body:focus`, which gives your background the `background-color: #3c3d41;`, but without `:focus` your body gets the `background: transparent;`..

So give your `body` the `background-color: #3c3d41;` and everything should be fine.

Comment: Ahh I okay - yeah lack of planning on the CSS! I had originally given the body:focus the background color because before IE8 was ignoring my background color and making it white when loaded. I then read that IE8 sometimes loads the body:focus state. Will make the amend and update back!

Comment: Removing body:focus makes my whole site load on white despite me setting the background.

Comment: Gave the body a class and set the background color. Fixed both issue :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :)

Comment: Only because you pointed me in the right direction :P thanks again greatly appreciated

Comment: I will indeed - I will just post the whole solution as well :P

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue:

Despite

```
html, body {  
    background-color: #3c3d41;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

My page was loading as white background. To fix that I did:

```
html, body, body:focus {  
    background-color: #3c3d41;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

To fix the background color change I was getting with textareas:

```
body.body-bg {
    background-color: #3c3d41;
}
```

Comment: I recommend putting this in your original question at the bottom. Otherwise it will get deleted most likely..

Comment: @Sebsemillia - No, that's exactly opposite of what we want. If this is a legitimate answer to the question asked, it should not be part of the question, but should be its own answer.

Comment: @BradLarson Look at his question and my answer. He didn't even provide code in the first place, just in his solution. So that is not really the answer to his question, but my "hint in the right direction", was the answer to "his" problem..